# JSoup character encoding issue #2

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

I'm constructing a JSoup document like this:

```
String user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/A.B     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/X.Y.Z.W Safari/A.B.";
String url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC24391/?tool=pubmed";
Document doc = return Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(user_agent).get();
```

Then, I save to file using `doc.toString()` and in the saved file I see characters replaced by `?`.  For example `5 μm` will become `5 ?m`.

If I change output settings to use ISO-8859-1 charset, it seems ok.

Can anyone explain why this is?  From my understanding the original html page is UTF-8, which is the default Jsoup encoding..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me. Your problem is caused elsewhere.

Most probable cause is that you didn't save the file using UTF-8. You should be using [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) to write characters in a specified character encoding to the file.

```
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

Also, you need to make sure that the file viewer or whatever process you use *after* saving the file is also using UTF-8 throughout the entire pipeline. See also [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  It was using the default charset on the Java save which was "MacRoman".  Thanks very much!